apple store does not show balance of my apple account
When I open the apple store on MacOS, or on my iPad, it is supposed to show the balance of my Apple account under my name; at least that's what the Apple support pages say.
However in my case, nothing is shown. This is supposed to mean that my balance is zero.
But when - on MacOS - I click on my name and then on "Account settings", the section "Apple Account" does show the correct balance.
How come?
UPDATE
I found that it's even more bizarre. What I described above, applies to MacOS on my Macbook, and the correct balance shown in the Apple Account  (but not on the AppStore page) is around 60€.
When I use MacOS on my iMac (same Apple ID of course), the balance is shown on the AppStore page, but as around 90€.

Have you asked Apple?

I once had to sign off and sign in again to see the correct balance.
